# Can you unlink your real name from your Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, display-names

I created a Stack Overflow account and then at some point I logged in with Facebook so my real name was linked to my Stack Overflow account.

At the beginning I didn't mind but now I realise that my competitors might be checking the questions I make and I don't want that for several reasons.

I was able to post with the original nickname that I used to create the account but if you Google my name this account will appear. Is there a way to unlink my name for good from this account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change your display name trivially simply by editing your profile. It is your display-name that is shown on posts, comments, etc. Just click "edit" on your profile (towards the top of the page).

What we *can't* do is erase the internet's history (including google's index, etc) that you used a different display name at some point, nor can we erase the fact that there are public data dumps that will use the old name. The internet doesn't have a "delete" button.

Comment: Indeed,  I think you need to [contact your ISP](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Mr-Keyboard,-Mr-Internet,-and-Support-from-Mr-James.aspx) to have things actually deleted off the Internet